# Tag firing multiple time - at wits end

Tags: google-tag-manager

Would really appreacite any insights.

Issue: I have about 30 landing pages with forms and a global footer sign up. Unfortunately there is nothing unitue to trigger on - they all have the same form ID and form text etc are blank.

What I have done do far:
[This is global enews letter sign up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1eFf.png)

[This is a landing page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYSYR.png)

Because the click text Sign me up for Educators eNews is in both the form it's triggering everytime.

Any help would really be apprecaited

Comment: This is a poorly worded question, but it looks like you're just not using enough conditions to go with your triggers. Try using the url as a condition. Or better yet, use the same trigger and tag for all of them, but then use a CJS or LUT variable to set another dimension to distinguish between them if URL itself is not enough.